# How can I load my generation dom function before the eventListener in my JS

Tags: javascript, dom, loading, event-listener

[image]

I want to fix the  Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, I think I have to found a way to load the function in my js before the eventListener , because I don't have that part in my html, the msgtitle doesn't exist  ( it only loard after another eventListener ).

```js
const generateDiscution = (username, userID) => {
  let html = `<div class="msg-box" style="" rel="${userID}"><div class="msg-title">${username}<div class="close" >x</div> </div>`;
  html += `<div class="msg-wrap">
  <ul class="chat-list">
  </ul>
  <div class="msg-push"></div>`;
  html += `</div><form class="chat-input" style"" onsubmit="return false;"><input  class="message" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Ecrire votre message ..." />`;
  html += `<button class="submit">Envoyer</button></form></div></div></div>`;
  box.innerHTML += html;
};

// x closing

msgtitle.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (chatform.style.display === 'none' && msgwrap.style.display === 'none') {
    chatform.style.display = 'block';
    msgwrap.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    chatform.style.display = 'none';
    msgwrap.style.display = 'none';
  }
});


Array.from(discuElemt).forEach(elm => {
  elm.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const username = e.target.textContent;
    const userID = e.target.getAttribute('id');
    console.log(username);
    generateDiscution(username, userID);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a conceptual problem,  you are trying to add event to a non-existing element… preventDefault() don’t help on this case.
When working with dynamic elements creation, you need append events on element creation, like:

```
function createHelloButton(){

    const buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
    buttonElement.textContent = "Click Here"

    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        alert('Hello world');
});
    document.body.appendChild(buttonElement);
}
```